# Jasny Bootstrap & Emberjs

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

I'm reading [this](https://pbatey.wordpress.com/2015/05/15/bootstrap-jasny-bootstrap-ember/) article and the author points out the following :

> In app/app.js adjust the ApplicationView so that it doesn’t insert the
>   wrapping ember-view div under the body — it interferes with the height
>   of the canvas div that jasny-bootstrap uses.

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
  podModulePrefix: config.podModulePrefix,
  Resolver: Resolver,
  ApplicationView:Ember.View.extend({tagName:''})
});
```

The thing is that i'm running Emberjs 2.6 with no views. How can i accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Hi Rentonie. The short bad news is that you can't remove the root div under the body, Ember needs to hook into it. The short good news is that you used to have one div per route, but now you only have one per application. I suggest maybe copying some of the CSS and target the div tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like locks said in comment, you can't remove root div under the body.
You please add the following CSS, this will remove need for setting tagName='' to application view. I tried this, it's working well.

```
:root,
.ember-application,
.ember-application>div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Got that answer from this..you can read for more about this issue https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11486